# tuple vector and initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, initializer-list

I tried to compile the following snippets with gcc4.7

```
vector<pair<int,char> > vp = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'}};
//For pair vector, it works like a charm.

vector<tuple<int,double,char> > vt = {{1,0.1,'a'},{2,4.2,'b'}};
```

However, for the vector of tuples, the compiler complains:

> error: converting to ‘std::tuple’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple<  >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {int, double, char};  = void; _Elements = {int, double, char}]’

The error info spilled by the compiler is total gibberish for me, and I have no idea how were the constructors of tuple implemented, yet I do know they're totally okay with uniform initialization (like: `tuple<int,float,char>{1,2.2,'X'}`), therefore, I wonder if the problem I encountered is only a TODO of the compiler or it's something defined by the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 16):

The relevant `std::tuple` constructors are `explicit`. This means that what you want to do is not possible, since the syntax you want to use is defined in terms of copy initialization (which forbids calling an `explicit` constructor). In contrast, `std::tuple<int, float, char> { 1, 2.2, 'X' }` uses direct initialization. `std::pair` does have non-`explicit` constructors only.

Either use direct-initialization or one of the Standard tuple factory function (e.g. `std::make_tuple`).

Comment: It's been made conditionally explicit (non-explicit in this case) in C++17.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually doable, with c++11 features.

Yes the initializer_list wants all its element to be of the same type. The trick is that we can create a wrapper class that can be `static_cast` to all the types we want. This is easy to achieve:

```
 template <typename... tlist>
 class MultiTypeWrapper {
 };

 template <typename H>
 class MultiTypeWrapper<H> {
 public:
   MultiTypeWrapper() {}

   MultiTypeWrapper(const H &value) : value_(value) {}

   operator H () const {
     return value_;
   }
 private:
   H value_;
 };

 template <typename H, typename... T>
 class MultiTypeWrapper<H, T...> 
   : public MultiTypeWrapper<T...> {

 public:
   MultiTypeWrapper() {}

   MultiTypeWrapper(const H &value) : value_(value) {}

   // If the current constructor does not match the type, pass to its ancestor.
   template <typename C>
   MultiTypeWrapper(const C &value) : MultiTypeWrapper<T...>(value) {}

   operator H () const {
     return value_;
   }
 private:
   H value_;
 };
```

With the implicit conversion constructors, we can pass something like {1,2.5,'c',4} to an initializer_list (or vector, which implicitly converts the initializer_list) of type MultiTypeWrapper. This means that we can not write a function like **below** to accept such intializer_list as argument:

```
template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> create_tuple(std::vector<unit_test::MultiTypeWrapper<T...> > init) {
  ....
}
```

We use another trick to cast each value in the vector to its original type (note that we provide implicit conversion in the definition of `MultiTypeWrapper`) and assign it to the corresponding slot in a tuple. It's like a recursion on template arguments:

```
template <int ind, typename... T>
class helper {
public:
  static void set_tuple(std::tuple<T...> &t, const std::vector<MultiTypeWrapper<T...> >& v) {
    std::get<ind>(t) = static_cast<typename std::tuple_element<ind,std::tuple<T...> >::type>(v[ind]);
    helper<(ind-1),T...>::set_tuple(t,v);
  }
};



template <typename... T>
class helper<0, T...> {
public:
  static void set_tuple(std::tuple<T...> &t, const std::vector<MultiTypeWrapper<T...> >& v) {
    std::get<0>(t) = static_cast<typename std::tuple_element<0,std::tuple<T...> >::type>(v[0]);
  }
};



template <typename... T>
std::tuple<T...> create_tuple(std::vector<unit_test::MultiTypeWrapper<T...> > init) {
  std::tuple<T...> res;
  helper<sizeof...(T)-1, T...>::set_tuple(res, init);
  return res;
}
```

Note that we have to create the helper class for `set_tuple` since c++ does not support function specialization. Now if we want to test the code:

```
auto t = create_tuple<int,double,std::string>({1,2.5,std::string("ABC")});
printf("%d %.2lf %s\n", std::get<0>(t), std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t).c_str());
```

The output would be:

```
1 2.50 ABC
```

This is tested on my desktop with clang 3.2

Hope my input helps :)

Comment: Cool, but I don't think the OP was looking to write a wrapper class just to be able to push tuples into a vector. At least, I am not going to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Annoying isn't it? I was also using pairs before - in a similar scenario and was surprised tuples do not support this, as the {} initialization syntax saves a lot of clutter. You can insert the elements manually in containers using **make_tuple**, so:

```
vt.push_back(make_tuple(2,4.2,'b'));
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the accolades just for initializing the tuple, you must use the keyword tuple instead

```
vector<tuple<int, int>> my_vec{
    tuple<int, int> { 1, 15 },
    tuple<int, int> { 2, 100 }
};
```

C++ 11